# How could I judge If a string prefix of another string by ascii code in Python?

Tags: python, string, ascii, prefix

For example, now we have pattern 'frei', and we have some names like 'freiburg', 'freicking', 'flensburg' and 'freking'. Now I want to judge if the pattern is the prefix of those names(all letters are lowercase).

someone gave the solution like this:

```
name = ['freiburg', 'freicking', 'flensburg', 'freking']
hit = []
pattern = 'frei'
lower = 'frei'
upper = 'frei{'
for i in name:
    if lower <= i <= upper:
        hit.append(i)
```

well, I think this is a very fantanstic mehtod. But I don't know what the principle of it is. Could someone tell me why the lower and upper string look like this? And why a character '{' will be used here? I think the sum of ascii code of 'freiburg' is larger than 'frei{', but why is it actually still smaller than 'frei{' ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This looks like a rather fragile and complicated way to do the equivalent of `startswith`. It's based on the (wrong) idea that '{' would come in sorting order after all letters. That is wrong. For example, `'freißenbüttel' < 'frei{'` is false, and the same would happen with lots of characters.

Comment: yes. I think all names have been converted to latin letters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by ensuring that the unicode codes of corresponding characters  to be compared are between the following boundaries:

```
[ord(i) for i in 'frei']
# [102, 114, 101, 105]

[ord(i) for i in 'frei{']
# [102, 114, 101, 105, 123]
```

Note that `{` comes right after `z` in the table:

```
ord('z')
# 122

ord('{')
# 123
```

Hence anything either  lower than the first sequence of codes or larger than the second is not considered. This becomes quite clear if you try sorting the sequence of strings, including the boundaries:

```
sorted(['fra', 'frei', 'frei{', 'freidja', 'freia', 'from'])
# ['fra', 'frei', 'freia', 'freidja', 'frei{', 'from']
```

So basically any string starting with `frei`, and followed by other letters will be smaller than `'frei{'`, since `{` is larger than `z`.

However, as mentioned by thierry in the comments, this assumes that the subsequent characters to be matched will be from the latin alphabet. Codes for characters from other alphabets will come after `{`, and not fall in that boundary.

Also, a much simpler (and probably the right) approach for this could be to just use `startswith` from the `str` class, which as its name indicates, returns a boolean if the string  starts with the specified substring:

```
[i for i in name if i.startswith('frei')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The original content of this problem is that we have a binary tree(class) to store a lot of data about cities(node.key = name, node.value = location) and also we have built a method named lookup(lower, upper) in this class. And we need to use lookup(lower, upper) this methode to find out which cities have a prefix with the given string(like 'frei'). So I can't use startwith this module. But thanks for your answer. I have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.startswith` function?

Example:

```
names = ['freiburg', 'freicking', 'flensburg', 'freking']
hit = []
pattern = 'frei'
for name in names:
    if name.startswith(pattern):
        hit.append(i)
```

Comment: good idea. but i need to solve a speical problem, so I am still trying to use upper and lower.